# "String?' is not convertible to 'NSString'" (after Xcode 7 migration)

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Hello I'm developing project (finishing it in objective-c) but one class was writed in Swift. After migration to XCODE 7 for ios9 compiler back to me with Error:  'String?' is not convertible to 'NSString'
for code:

```
if let view = self.emailTextField.rightView {
                    if (self.emailTextField.text as NSString).validateEmail() {
                        self.emailTextField.rightView?.alpha = 1
                    } else {
                        self.emailTextField.rightView?.alpha = 0
                    }
                }
```

Any advice from Swift2 Bosses :) ?

Comment: Do you *know* what the question mark in the error message "String? is not  convertible ..." means?

Comment: Optional strings are not convertible to NSString, you have to make it non-optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boss advice:

`self.emailTextField.text as NSString` becomes `self.emailTextField.text! as NSString`

:)

Comment: Heh the best thing is that I've tried that with no success ... now try again after Your post and It work nice Boss ;)

Comment: I'll ... have to w8 4mintues more :P